# Pandas: Find cell index: case insensitive

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that looks for a value in a panda dataframe using the 'isin' builtin function. The problem is that I would like to make this function case insensitive. I could parse every column to a serie and use the 'str.contains' but I find it a little ugly. Would you know a nice way to do this?

Here is the function returning the index and col of a given world:

```
  def find_pos(self, titres):
    bool_table = self.document.isin(titres)
    for i in range(bool_table.shape[0]):
        for j in range(bool_table.shape[1]):
            boolean = bool_table.iloc[i][j]
            if boolean:
                return i, j

    print(titres, " not found in csv", file=sys.stderr)
    return -1, -1
```

A working solution is to use lambdas:

```
bool_table = self.document.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower()).isin([x.lower() for x in titres])
```

As I am new to python, maybe this isn't the nicest way to do this?

Comment: Could you add example data with desired output? Please take a look at how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: `your_columns.str.lower()`?

Comment: Well an easy exemple would be as titres: ["TOTO"] and the dataFrame contains "toto" in cell 3, 3: the output would be 3,3

Comment: @RockyLi yes that's my first guess, I just wanted to know if there is not a nicer way to do this :) I'm new with pandas!

Comment: You can match using that too. just `blah.isin(stuff.str.lower())`

Comment: Yes but imagine the df contains "Toto", it wouldn't work isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is first finding the matching column, then find the row index.
Use regex for case insensitive matching.

One sample methods is

```
def find_pos(search):
    pattern = '(?i)' + search  
    # search in each column
    for column in df:
        df2 = df[df[column].str.contains(pattern, regex=True)]
        if not df2.empty:
            # find row index and column index
            return (df2.index[0], df2.columns.get_loc(column))

idx = find_pos('to')
print(idx)
```

I tried in the following sample data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name', 'Location'])
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Mathew', 'Houston']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Tony', 'New York']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Jerom', 'Los Angeles']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Aby', 'Dallas']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Elma', 'Memphis']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Zack', 'Chicago']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Lisa', 'New Orleans']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Nita', 'Las Vegas']
```